# how can i give my footer container the same width from content if that slide left

Tags: jquery, width, slide

if i open my testsite: http://devauth.labscope.de/htmlapp/report-overview_test.html

and click on the top left icon (filter) so the content and footer slide left and i see that the footer container don't have the same width as content container because the scrollbar in the Content make this.

[image]

How can i solve this in my Code?:

```
jQuery('.filter').on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var state   = $(this).data('state'),
            wrapper = $('#content').data('left'),
            footer  = $('#footer').data('left');

        jQuery("#content").animate({
            left: state ? wrapper : -250,
            duration: 1000
        }, "normal");

        jQuery("#footer").animate({
            left: state ? footer : -250,
            duration: 1000
        }, "normal");

        jQuery(this).data('state', !state);


    });
```

I hope someone have idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#footer').width($('#content').width());
});
```

Comment: It's works but if i slide back and make my browser width wider and i have a problem. So i need before state. How can i solve this ?

Comment: Why don't you attach to the window resize event and set the width? e.g. `$(window).resize(function() { 
    $('#footer').width($('#content').width());
});`

Comment: No. i use this only in my slide function

Comment: You should be able to add this one line into your slide function to have the footer update as you slide `$('#footer').width($('#content').width());`

Comment: jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        jQuery('#footer').css('width', '100%');

    });